# Android How to change fragment TextView using java in MainActivivity

Tags: java, android, fragment

I insert one fragment in activity_main.xml using java, i put fragment in linear layout in activity_main.
Fragment xml file has one textView.

How can i change TextView when app start from MainActivity using java, when app start and when it called onCreate?
I try few solution form stacoverflow but i can get this to work.
Emulator get crashed when he start to load app.

Here is activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.fragment_promjenaviewprekojave.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutFragment_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Fragment code:

```
package com.example.android.fragment_promjenaviewprekojave;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here is xml file for that fragment who contain only 1 TextView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.fragment_promjenaviewprekojave.BlankFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragmentTextView_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the MainActivity.java from where I want to change fragment `TextView`

```
package com.example.android.fragment_promjenaviewprekojave;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BlankFragment objA = new BlankFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linearLayoutFragment_id, objA);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragmentTextView_id);
        textView.setText("We add text to fragment TextView");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `BlankFragment` code, change

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}
```

to :

```
//Declare a member to hold a reference to your TextView
private TextView  myTextView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    myTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentTextView_id);
    myTextView .setText("Whatever text you want");
    return (v);
}

//Also declare a function to modify the text on your fragment
public void setCustomText(String str) {
    if (myTextView != null) {
      myTextView.setText(str);
    }
}
```

Now back in your activity, you can call

```
objA.setCustomText("Hello World!");
```

Bare in mind that you will need to store a reference to `objA` in your activity, such as

```
private BlankFragment  objA;
```

The `onCreate` will then be :

```
objA = new BlankFragment();
```

Lastly, this method works fine once the views are all in place and drawn.
If you're looking to change the text inside the fragment at creation, you will want to use a `newInstance` pattern on the fragment, where you can pass the text as an argument.

Something like this :

```
objA = BlankFragment.newInstance("Hello world");
```

Where `newInstance` is defined in your fragment as follow :

```
public static BlankFragment newInstance(String str) {
    BlankFragment f = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("TextTag", str);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return (f);
}
```

And then you can retrieve this value in the `onCreate` of your Fragment like this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    myTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragmentTextView_id);
    String text = getArguments().getString("TextTag", "");
    myTextView .setText(text);
    return (v);
}
```

Comment: It is working but that is change from fragment. Can I change it from MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 1):

In your xml, you should have a fragment container. Assuming the ID of this is `fragment_id`:

For support library,

```
BlankFragment blankFrag = (BlankFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
                                              findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

Or else for non-support library `Fragment`:

```
BlankFragment blankFrag = (BlankFragment)getFragmentManager().
                                             findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

You will also need a public method in the `BlankFragment` class with a signature like `setTextViewText(String text)` and then call it from `MainActivity` like `blankFrag.setTextViewText("my text");`